# Rename filename of customer download(s) to File Label Name + extension in Woocommerce (for checkout page & order email)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Some customer downloads in Woocommerce don't have a fancy filename on the server, but I'd like customer order downloads to be renamed to the corresponding 'File Label Name' + file extension upon download. I need this to work for the download buttons on the checkout/order-received page but also for the download links in the order complete email sent to the customer. Some Products contain multiple downloads.

I think I'd like to use "Code Snippets". Any ideas how to do this?

Note: since some Products contain multiple downloads, it would be great if the download name can be 'Product Name' or 'File Label Name' for products with a single downloadable file, and 'Product Name - File Label Name' for products with multiple files.

Many thanks in advance!

This is what I've tried so far with my poor programming skills, it works ok on the checkout page but NOT for the order completed email download links, so I simply use the Product Name there for the downloads.

I've copied order-download.php to the directory of my child theme and added "&fancy_new_file_name=" . esc_html( $download['download_name'] )" below // DOWNLOAD BUTTON:

```
// DOWNLOAD BUTTON!
// MY MOD: copy item name to URL as fancy_new_file_name (code snippet renames download!)
case 'download-file':
    echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['download_url'] ) . "&fancy_new_file_name=" . esc_html( $download['download_name'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-MyAccount-downloads-file button alt">' . esc_html( $download['download_name'] ) . '</a>';
    break;
```

I've added a code snippet running everywhere:

```
function change_woocommerce_file_download_filename( $filename, $product_id ) {
// First check if isset($_GET['fancy_new_file_name']) in URL
    if(!isset($_GET['fancy_new_file_name'])) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        // Use Product name to rename file (unfortunately all EMAIL downloads will have the same product name)
        $_GET['fancy_new_file_name'] = $product->get_name();
    }
    // Get the file extension from the processed file name.
    $filetype = wp_check_filetype( $filename );

    // $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $new_file_name = $_GET['fancy_new_file_name'];

    // Join the new file name with file extension with (.).
    return join( '.', array( $new_file_name, $filetype['ext'] ) );
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_file_download_filename', 'change_woocommerce_file_download_filename', 10, 2 );
```